# How to wire a 3-way switch with 4 wires?

Tags: electrical, dimmer-switch, multiway-switch

[image]Switch location 1.

Switch location 2
[image]

Switch trying to wire
[image]

Comment: Can you post photos looking into the backs of the switch boxes please?

Comment: We really, really, really need that photo of the back of the box.  Not only is this a 4-way, but it looks like the wiring is really messed up, to the point of being actively dangerous.  DO NOT hook up any ground wires until talking to us.   To be sure we really need photos looking into the back of the box.   Do your best; even if they're kinda dim, I can brighten 'em up in Photoshop.

Comment: Also, do you have any switches elsewhere in the house that you don't know what they do, or seem to do nothing?

Answer (score 1):

That switch looks like a 4-way switch which would be used in addition to 2 - 3 way switches when a light is to be switched from 3 or more locations. Your new switch would have to replace one of the two 3 way switches or you'll have to get a 4 way dimmer switch (if they even make one) to replace the 4 way switch shown in your pictures.

CORRECTION: I thought the pictures were of the same switch but I see that there are two different 4 way switches. Do you have 4 switches controlling the light?